# Как распаковать содержимое образа Docker?

Tags: docker

Допустим я нашел ссылку на файлы которые мне нужны

```
docker pull asteinlein/php56-pthreads
```

Установил докер, закачал, получил сообщение что все успешно закачано.
Если я правильно понимаю, докер закачивает все 'репозитории' в свою папку

```
/var/lib/docker
```

Зашел туда с под суперюзера через mc и понял что там всё хранится сложным образом...

Вопрос в том как распаковать в папку то, что я закачал, используя:

```
docker pull
```

Если я правильно понял, то докер хранит всё в образах images и получается чтобы извлечь файлы, нужно или смонтировать образ, или открыть его. Вопрос в том, как его смонтировать или открыть?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете запустить контейнер и скопировать находящиеся внутри файлы (вне зависимости от статуса контейнера):

```
etki@kepler:~ > docker run --name carrier ubuntu
etki@kepler:~ > docker cp carrier:/etc/issue issue
etki@kepler:~ > cat issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

Тем не менее, вам это вряд ли поможет. Насколько понимаю, вам нужна поддержка pthreads, и единственный верный путь в этом случае - разобраться, как компилировать расширения PHP самостоятельно.